# Ubuntu Server LTS 22.04 install fails at Storage Configuration stage

Tags: server, system-installation

I'm attempting to install Server 22.04 on a dell R430. The installer crashes at the Storage Configuration stage. I would like to use a custom partitioning scheme. After defining my desired partitions, I select Done, and the screen freezes. I tried again, same issue. Then I tried the default partitioning scheme ('Use Entire Disk' or similar). Same issue. The screen freezes. I can use the left/right arrow keys to return to a command prompt, but the installer is unresponsive.

The server has one 240G SSD, and 2x2TB HDDs.

Comment: Which disk have you selected (in the top right corner of `gparted`'s screen)? None of the selected disk's partitions may be `mount`ed.